# Custom loss function that skips the NaN input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am building an autoencoder, my data has NaN values in it. How do I create a custom (MSE) loss function, that does not compute loss if it encounters a NaN in the validation data?

Got a hint from the web:

```
def nan_mse(y_actual, y_predicted):
    per_instance = tf.where(tf.is_nan(y_actual),
                            tf.zeros_like(y_actual),
                            tf.square(tf.subtract(y_predicted, y_actual)))
    return tf.reduce_mean(per_instance, axis=0)
```

But receive loss of NaN:

> Epoch 1/50
>    - 25s - loss: nan

When I try using the custom loss function in my callback function, after each epoch:

```
predictions = autoencoder.predict(x_pred)
mae = (nan_mse(x_pred, predictions))
```

> TypeError: Input 'e' of 'Select' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 't'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, your loss function actually works well. The `nan` value probably comes from the predictions. Thus the condition `tf.is_nan(y_actual)` doesn't filter it out.
To filter out the prediction's `nan` you should do as follows:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np


def nan_mse(y_actual, y_predicted):
    stack = tf.stack((tf.is_nan(y_actual), 
                      tf.is_nan(y_predicted)),
                     axis=1)
    is_nans = K.any(stack, axis=1)
    per_instance = tf.where(is_nans,
                            tf.zeros_like(y_actual),
                            tf.square(tf.subtract(y_predicted, y_actual)))
    print(per_instance)
    return tf.reduce_mean(per_instance, axis=0)

print(nan_mse([1.,1.,np.nan,1.,0.], [1.,1.,0.,0.,np.nan]))
```

**Out:**

```
tf.Tensor(0.2, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Indeed the error in callback function comes from prediction data. But all the y_prediction consists of NaNs. This is an autoencoder and I was hoping that this loss would help me ignoring NaNs from input, and product non-NaN predictions. But it creates all NaN prediction.

Comment: @Geeocode  I have two questions with deference to your answer: I) in the case that 0 has a meaning like other values (for instance when we are dealing with temperature time series) replacing NAN by 0 does not seem  totally correct. II) if the objective is to filter NANs, when we do the averaging, should not we divide sum by the number of non-NAN elements of the tensor? Would you please update your answer based on these two questions? Many thanks.