# Predictions of Autoencoder are all NaNs because of using custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, loss-function

I am building an Autoencoder for gene expression data. Some genes are not expressed and have NaN in the input. My output (prediction) is all NaN. Here is my loss function:

```
def nan_mse(y_actual, y_predicted):
    per_instance = tf.where(tf.is_nan(y_actual),
    tf.zeros_like(y_actual),
    tf.square(tf.subtract(y_predicted, y_actual)))
    return tf.reduce_mean(per_instance, axis=0)
```

And model:

```
input_data = Input(shape=(1,num_genes))

#Leaky-Parametric-RelU
#Encoder
x = Dense(num_genes)(input_data)
encoder = PReLU()(x)

#Battleneck layer
encoded = Dense(64, activation = 'sigmoid')(encoder)

#Decoder
x = Dense(num_genes)(encoded)
decoder = PReLU()(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_data, decoder)
autoencoder.compile(loss=nan_mse, optimizer = 'adam') 
autoencoder.summary()

history = autoencoder.fit(x_train,x_train, epochs =50, verbose = 2),                      
 callbacks = [MyCustomCallback()])
```

My goal is to make network ignore NaN values, but it is important to preceive them in the input. Is this doable by completing the loss function?

Right now output is NaN. A user suggested here to edit code so:

```
def nan_mse(y_actual, y_predicted):
    stack = tf.stack((tf.is_nan(y_actual), 
                      tf.is_nan(y_predicted)),
                     axis=1)
    is_nans = tf.keras.backend.any(stack, axis=1)
    per_instance = tf.where(is_nans,
                            tf.zeros_like(y_actual),
                            tf.square(tf.subtract(y_predicted, y_actual)))
    print(per_instance)
    return tf.reduce_mean(per_instance, axis=0)
```

Now I get 0.0000e+00 as my loss, but that does not solve the root problem.

[Original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911740/custom-loss-function-that-skips-the-nan-input)

Comment: Please provide relevant codes, model architecture etc.  and some sample data to be able to help you.

Answer (score -2):

x=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/10.csv",index_col=False).groupby(['Column_name_optional']).mean().reset_index()

x = x.replace(np.nan, 0)

## this will replace all NaN with Zeros

Comment: I do not think that this is what the asker needs. By the level of the code presented in the question, I suspect the asker knows how to replace `nan` with zeros.